# How to use a for-loop on column ranges for plotting without using all combination of i and j?

Tags: r, for-loop, plot, likert

I am trying to print likert plots with a nested for-loop. Well, it works, but I would like the `for` function to not "retake" the `i` and `j`, which means I want to plot 1:5, 6:10, 11:15, and so on. But not all possible combinations of these variables.

```
library(likert)

for(i in c(1, 6, 11, 16)){
  for (j in c(5, 10, 15, 20)) {
    print(plot(likert(data.likert[, i:j])))
  }
}
```

Any better ideas?

Here comes a data example (sorry it is a bit long):

```
data.likert <- structure(list(
  Q1 = structure(c(5L,5L, 5L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L), .Label = c("Stimme überhaupt nicht zu", "Stimme eher nicht zu", "Weder noch", "Stimme eher zu", "Stimme voll und ganz zu", "Weiß nicht/keine Angabe"), class = "factor"), 
 Q2 = structure(c(5L,5L, 5L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L), .Label = c("Stimme überhaupt nicht zu", "Stimme eher nicht zu", "Weder noch", "Stimme eher zu", "Stimme voll und ganz zu", 
"Weiß nicht/keine Angabe"), class = "factor"), 
Q3 = structure(c(2L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 4L, 4L, 4L), .Label = c("Stimme überhaupt nicht zu", "Stimme eher nicht zu", "Weder noch", "Stimme eher zu", "Stimme voll und ganz zu", 
"Weiß nicht/keine Angabe"), class = "factor"), 
Q4 = structure(c(1L, 4L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 3L), .Label = c("Stimme überhaupt nicht zu", 
"Stimme eher nicht zu", "Weder noch", "Stimme eher zu", "Stimme voll und ganz zu", "Weiß nicht/keine Angabe"), class = "factor"), 
Q5 = structure(c(1L, 2L, 2L, 4L, 2L, 1L, 4L, 2L, 2L, 5L), .Label = c("Stimme überhaupt nicht zu", 
"Stimme eher nicht zu", "Weder noch", "Stimme eher zu", "Stimme voll und ganz zu", 
"Weiß nicht/keine Angabe"), class = "factor"), 
Q6 = structure(c(1L, 
1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("Stimme überhaupt nicht zu", 
"Stimme eher nicht zu", "Weder noch", "Stimme eher zu", "Stimme voll und ganz zu", 
"Weiß nicht/keine Angabe"), class = "factor"), 
Q7 = structure(c(4L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 3L, NA, 2L, 2L, 2L, NA), .Label = c("Stimme überhaupt nicht zu", 
"Stimme eher nicht zu", "Weder noch", "Stimme eher zu", "Stimme voll und ganz zu", "Weiß nicht/keine Angabe"), class = "factor"), 
Q8 = structure(c(4L, 4L, 4L, 2L, 2L, 4L, 1L, NA, 2L, NA), .Label = c("Stimme überhaupt nicht zu", "Stimme eher nicht zu", "Weder noch", "Stimme eher zu", "Stimme voll und ganz zu", 
"Weiß nicht/keine Angabe"), class = "factor"), 
Q9 = structure(c(3L, 2L, 2L, 5L, 3L, 5L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 4L), .Label = c("Stimme überhaupt nicht zu", 
 "Stimme eher nicht zu", "Weder noch", "Stimme eher zu", "Stimme voll und ganz zu", 
 "Weiß nicht/keine Angabe"), class = "factor"), 
Q10 = structure(c(5L, 5L, 2L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 3L, 5L, 4L, 5L), .Label = c("Stimme überhaupt nicht zu", 
 "Stimme eher nicht zu", "Weder noch", "Stimme eher zu", "Stimme voll und ganz zu", 
 "Weiß nicht/keine Angabe"), class = "factor"), 
Q11 = structure(c(5L,5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 4L, 5L, 5L), .Label = c("Stimme überhaupt nicht zu", 
"Stimme eher nicht zu", "Weder noch", "Stimme eher zu", "Stimme voll und ganz zu", 
"Weiß nicht/keine Angabe"), class = "factor"), 
Q12 = structure(c(5L, 5L, 2L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 5L), .Label = c("Stimme überhaupt nicht zu", 
 "Stimme eher nicht zu", "Weder noch", "Stimme eher zu", "Stimme voll und ganz zu", 
 "Weiß nicht/keine Angabe"), class = "factor"), 
Q13 = structure(c(5L, 5L, 4L, NA, 4L, 5L, 5L, NA, 3L, 5L), .Label = c("Stimme überhaupt nicht zu", 
 "Stimme eher nicht zu", "Weder noch", "Stimme eher zu", "Stimme voll und ganz zu", 
 "Weiß nicht/keine Angabe"), class = "factor"), 
Q14 = structure(c(2L, 2L, 4L, 1L, 4L, 1L, 4L, 3L, 2L, 4L), .Label = c("Stimme überhaupt nicht zu", 
 "Stimme eher nicht zu", "Weder noch", "Stimme eher zu", "Stimme voll und ganz zu", 
 "Weiß nicht/keine Angabe"), class = "factor"), 
Q15 = structure(c(1L,  1L, 4L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, NA, 1L, 2L), .Label = c("Stimme überhaupt nicht zu", 
 "Stimme eher nicht zu", "Weder noch", "Stimme eher zu", "Stimme voll und ganz zu", 
 "Weiß nicht/keine Angabe"), class = "factor")), row.names = c(NA, 
 10L), class = "data.frame")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could just take a single `v` and add four to get the second value.

```
for (i in c(1, 6, 11)) print(plot(likert(data.likert[, i:(i + 4)])))
```

Or, using `lapply`.

```
lapply(c(1, 6, 11), \(i) plot(likert(data.likert[, i:(i + 4)])))
```

Answer (score 2):

If we need to take the sequence from corresponding elements, use `Map`

```
Map(function(i, j) plot(likert(data.likert[, i:j])),
      c(1, 6, 11, 16), c(5, 10, 15, 20))
```

NOTE: In the OP's `dput` dataset, there are only 15 columns (assuming that it is just a subset of the original data)

---

Or the same in a `for` loop would be to create two `vector` sequence and loop over the sequence of one of the vectors, get the vector values based on the sequence index, return the sequence (`:`), extract the columns, apply `likert` and `plot`

```
v1 <- c(1, 6, 11, 16)
v2 <- c(5, 10, 15, 20)
for(i in seq_along(v1)) {
    print(plot(likert(data.likert[, v1[i]:v2[i])))
}
```